# Problem in Performing Database Operation on Berkeley DB in java

Tags: java, berkeley-db

I got the error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:288)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:114)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:89)
at sqljdbc.Sqlitejdbc1.main(Sqlitejdbc1.java:20)
```

Comment: Is it really Berkeley DB? I only see SQLite in the stack trace.